# Subclass & Superclass Uses (Android)

Tags: android, arraylist, subclass, extend, superclass

Background:  I have a fairly popular niche app that I want to extend by creating a master library of common code that I can use to produce more, similar apps with minimal work.

Superclasses (in the library):
BaseTheme

Subclasses (separate apps):
Theme (extends BaseTheme, provides a few specific methods for each app).
Comparator

In the Comparator class I have an Arraylist.  I would like to move Comparator to the library but in doing so, Arraylist throws an error since Theme doesn't exist in the library

I tried changing Arraylist to Arraylist thinking that Theme was an extension of BaseTheme and would be allowed but that didn't work when I tried to create a Theme in the Arraylist.

In the app code:

```
private ArrayList<Theme> mThemes;
private MyComparator mComparator;

mThemes = mComparator.compare(mSortType, mSortAorD, true, mThemes);
```

Error: The method compare(int, int, Boolean, ArrayList) in the type MyComparator is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, boolean, ArrayList)
-I believe this is because the constructor for the comparator has ArrayList since Theme doesn't exist in the library code

Is there any way to make this happen or do I need to keep it the way it is currently (Comparator in the app code)?

Library Code:
        public class MyComparator  {

```
private static Context mCtx;


public MyComparator(Context ctx) {
  mCtx = ctx;

}
public ArrayList<BaseTheme> compare(final int type, final int sort, Boolean flurry, ArrayList<BaseTheme> list) {
    Comparator<BaseTheme> myComparator = getComparator(Sort.SORT_ALPHABETICAL, Sort.DESC, flurry);
    Collections.sort(list, myComparator);

    myComparator = getComparator(type, sort, flurry);
    Collections.sort(list, myComparator);
    return list;
}

public abstract class BaseTheme {
public String mName;
public String mCreator;
public String mDate;
public String mAddress;
public int mThemeID;
public int mPopularity;
public boolean mIsFavorite;
public boolean mIsVisible;
public Context mCtx;

public BaseTheme(int themeID, String name, String creator, String date, String address, Boolean favorite, 
        Boolean visible, int popularity, boolean isFavorite, boolean isVisible, Context ctx) {

    setThemeID(themeID);
    setName(name);
    setCreator(creator);
    setDate(date);
    setAddress(address);
    setPopularity(popularity);
    mIsFavorite = isFavorite;
    mIsVisible = isVisible;
    mCtx = ctx;
}
```

App code:

```
public class FragmentBaseGridActivity extends AbsListViewBaseActivity {

private ArrayList<Theme> mThemes;

private void refreshGrid() {
    mThemes = mComparator.compare(mSortType, mSortAorD, true, mThemes);
    ImageAdapter ad = (ImageAdapter) listView.getAdapter();
    ad.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }

public class Theme extends BaseTheme{

public String mStyle;

public Theme(int themeID, String name, String creator, String date, String style, String address, Boolean favorite, 
        Boolean visible, int popularity, Context ctx) {
    super(themeID, name, creator, date, address, favorite, visible, popularity, favorite, visible, ctx);

}
```

Comment: Show more of your code. Because all I get from your question is that you have some problem with inheritance. But what is that problem?..

Comment: specifically the comparator would be good.

Comment: Added relevant code portions